# Why are values converted to strings in the rollapply window?

Tags: r, zoo

More newbie questions... I am trying to understand why rollapply is turning all my columns to strings. Suppose I have this:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4), 
                 col2=c("a","b","c","d"), 
                 col3=c("!","@","#","$"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F))
> v <- zoo(df, toupper(df$col2))
> v
  col1 col2 col3
A 1    a    !   
B 2    b    @   
C 3    c    #   
D 4    d    $
```

And then I run rollapply:

```
> rollapply(v, 2, by.column = F, function(x) { 
+     sum(x[,"col1"])
+ })
 Error in sum(x[, "col1"]) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Why is col1 now a character? and how do I fix it so I get a slice of my original zoo object in each window?

Comment: A 2d zoo object is a matrix with an index attribute and zoo class and matrices can only have one type.  If you try to mix different types R will convert them all to the lowest common denominator.  Note that this conversion was done when creating the zoo object v. It is already of this sort when you apply rollapply. rollapply itself does not cause this.

Comment: `zoo` converts your data to a matrix and a matrix can't hold mixed types. Since you have some character values, everything gets bumped to a character value.

Comment: thank you for all your help today. Any idea on how I can fix it? (I have a lot of columns in my zoo object and would like to be using the correct column types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolled my own rollapply function based on some reading of other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947301/can-rollapply-return-a-list-of-matrices) on SO. This just returns the indexes into the data (i.e. the zoo object):

```
rollapply.list <- function(data, width, FUN) {
  len <- NROW(data)
  add <- rep(0:(len-width),each=width)
  lst <- rep(1:(width),len-width+1)
  seq.list <- split(lst+add, add)
  lapply(seq.list, FUN)
}
```

and then apply the indexes to the original data like:

```
rollapply.list(data=v, width=2, FUN=function(x) {
     slice <- v[x]   #slice out indexes from the original zoo object
     ...
}
```