# Linear model fitting iteratively and calculate the Variable Importance with varImp() for all predictors over the iterations

Tags: r, loops, iteration, linear-regression, lm

I would like to iteratively fit a linear model (= LM) and calculate the variable importance of the individual variables/predictors after each iteration with the `caret::varImp()` function. My data table and the number of days look like this (the number of columns of `dt.train` can always differ and the `days` variable also):

```
d <- 50  
## Create random data table: ##
dt.train <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 366),
                       "DE" = rnorm(366, 35, 1), "Wind" = rnorm(366, 5000, 2), "Solar" = rnorm(366, 3, 2),
                       "Nuclear" = rnorm(366, 100, 5), "ResLoad" = rnorm(366, 200, 3),  check.names = FALSE)
```

I also already have a function that calculates this for me every `d` days (here `d<-50`):

```
varImportance <- function(data){
  ## Model fitting: ##
  lmModel <- stats::lm(DE ~ .-1-date, data = data)
  
  terms <- attr(lmModel$terms , "term.labels")
  varimp <- caret::varImp(lmModel)
  importance <- data[, .(date, imp = t(varimp))]
} 
## Get variable importance: ##
dt.importance <- dt.train[, varImportance(.SD), by = seq_len(nrow(dt.train)) %/% d]
```

Now I would like to have a loop that builds up the iteration for me as follows:

**1. Run:** Model fitting with the data from "2020-01-01" to "2020-02-20" (which are here exactly the 50 days)

**2. Run:** Model fitting with the data from "2020-01-02" to "2020-02-21"

**3. Run:** Model fitting with the data from "2020-01-03" to "2020-02-22"

**...** and so on

**Last run:** Model fitting with the data from "2020-11-11" to "2020-12-31"

---

The variable importance should then always be saved in a new table to match the model fitting, i.e.:

variable Importance of **1. Run:** should be declared for "2020-01-01",

variable Importance of **2. Run:** should be declared for "2020-01-02",

... and so on

variable Importance of **Last Run:** should be declared for "2020-11-11".

**How could this work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package.

Important arguments are :

- `width` to set the window
- `by.column = FALSE` to pass all the columns together to the model
- `aligned = 'left'` so that the roll window starts from the first data point on

As `rollapply` works on matrices, it converts `dates` mixed with `numeric` to `character`, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793824/why-are-values-converted-to-strings-in-the-rollapply-window), so that the `date` field had to be handled separately.

```r
library(data.table)
library(caret)
library(zoo)

d <- 50
## Create random data table: ##
dt.train <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 366),
                       "DE" = rnorm(366, 35, 1), "Wind" = rnorm(366, 5000, 2), "Solar" = rnorm(366, 3, 2),
                       "Nuclear" = rnorm(366, 100, 5), "ResLoad" = rnorm(366, 200, 3),  check.names = FALSE)

varImportance <- function(data){
  ## Model fitting: ##
  lmModel <- stats::lm(DE ~ .-1, data = data.table(data))
  terms <- attr(lmModel$terms , "term.labels")
  varimp <- caret::varImp(lmModel)
  importance <- t(varimp)
}

# Removing date because rollapply needs a unique type
Importance <- as.data.frame(zoo::rollapply(dt.train[,!"date"], 
                                           FUN = varImportance,
                                           width = d,
                                           by.column=FALSE,
                                           align='left')
                            )

# Adding back date
Importance <- cbind(dt.train[1:nrow(Importance),.(date)],Importance)

Importance
#>            date     Wind     Solar   Nuclear    ResLoad
#>   1: 2020-01-01 2.523219 1.0253985 0.1676970 0.80379590
#>   2: 2020-01-02 2.535376 1.3231915 0.3292608 0.78803748
#>   3: 2020-01-03 2.636790 1.5249620 0.4857825 0.85169700
#>   4: 2020-01-04 3.158113 1.1318521 0.1869724 0.24190772
#>   5: 2020-01-05 3.326954 1.0991870 0.2341736 0.09327451
#>  ---                                                   
#> 313: 2020-11-08 4.552528 0.8662639 0.8824743 0.22454327
#> 314: 2020-11-09 4.464356 0.8773634 0.8845554 0.19480862
#> 315: 2020-11-10 4.532254 0.8230178 0.7147899 0.38073588
#> 316: 2020-11-11 4.415192 0.7462676 0.8225977 0.32353235
#> 317: 2020-11-12 3.666675 0.3957351 0.6607121 0.19661800
```

This solution takes more time than the function you already use because it has 50 times more calculations than the chunck version. It also wasn't possible to use `data.table::frollapply` which AFAIK can only output a 1 dimensional vector.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, when I apply this to the GAM it doesn't work as hoped, the same for MARS model.

Comment: As in our previous discussions, each model comes with its constraints, and making sure that data fits within these constraints can be tedious. However, I see no fundamental reason for the above method not to work with other model types.